# NestJs Method not returning the same value depending on where it's called from

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a weird issue I cannot figure out. I'm storing `priceHistories` in memory in an array. When I call a get method, it doesn't return the same value depending on where I call the method from.

The original property and method:

```
@Injectable()
export class PricehistoryService {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(PricehistoryService.name);
    private priceHistories: PriceHistory[] = [];

    getPriceHistories(): PriceHistory[] {
        this.logger.log(this.priceHistories);
        return this.priceHistories;
    }

....

}
```

When called from this `Controller`, it returns the complete history

```
@Controller('pricehistory')
export class PricehistoryController {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(PricehistoryController.name);
    constructor(private readonly priceHistoryService: PricehistoryService) {}

    @Get()
    getCompletePriceHistory(): PriceHistory[] {
        this.logger.log('GET REQUEST: Complete price history');
        return this.priceHistoryService.getPriceHistories();
    }
}
```

Expected return (working on the above `Controller` call):

```
[
    {
        "naam": "karmeliet",
        "prices": [
            {
                "price": "2.5",
                "timestamp": 1683917722366
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However, when I call it from another `Service`, it just returns an empty array. The log in the `getPriceHistories()` also says that `this.priceHistories` is [].

```
@Injectable()
export class PricesService {
    private appSettings: AppSettings;
    private readonly logger = new Logger(PricesService.name);

    constructor(private readonly drinksService: DrinksService, private readonly priceHistoryService: PricehistoryService) {
        this.appSettings = {factor: 10, standaardafwijking: 2, minimum: 0.6, maximum: 2.5}
    }

    getCurrentPrices(): CurrentPrice[] {
        this.logger.log("Getting all current prices");
        let currentPrices: CurrentPrice[] = [];
        let priceHistories: PriceHistory[] = this.priceHistoryService.getPriceHistories();
        priceHistories.forEach(priceHistory => {
            let currentPriceTemp: CurrentPrice = {
                naam: priceHistory.naam,
                currentPrice: priceHistory.prices.at(priceHistory.prices.length - 1).price
            };
            currentPrices.push(currentPriceTemp);
        })

        return currentPrices;
    }
....
}
```

`priceHistories` here is `[]`

EDIT 1:

Apparently, any method called from the `PricesService` to either the `PricehistoryService` or the `DrinksService` returns an empty array. This doesn't happen when calling methods from other `Services`, just the `PricesService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the reason was I put the `pricesService` into the `AppModule`'s `providers`. Removing it did the trick.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { CronService } from './cron/cron.service';
import { DrinksModule } from './drinks/drinks.module';
import { PricehistoryModule } from './pricehistory/pricehistory.module';
import { PriceModule } from './price/price.module';
import { PriceController } from './price/price.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    DrinksModule,
    PricehistoryModule,
    PriceModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, PriceController],
  providers: [AppService, CronService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```